# How do I log the details of network traffic with .NET network tracing?

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest

My app is using its manifest's configuration settings (app.config; see xml below) to control .NET Network Tracing (as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/network-tracing). From what I understand, this is a "code-free" approach that is configured exclusively from the app.config file and no actual code is required to log anything.  In this case, I'm initializing listeners for a bunch of System.Net classes in a verbose fashion.  So I'm assuming it will automatically log any methods that are called - like capturing all of the network requests and responses (including exceptions especially) from an HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() method.  And it will automagically output to the file name specified in the initializeData attribute.

Except I don't see that file.  I'm following the example .config file from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing, as per my manifest below.  Either nothing is getting logged or the tracing isn't working at all. I have the "Define TRACE constant" box checked on the project's Build tab, and the MyApp.dll.config file in the /bin/Debug directory is a good copy of the main app.config file in the project.

Are my assumptions wrong and I have to write code? If so, where do I get the low-level network details (as per here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/interpreting-network-tracing)?  I looked into the docs on tracing in general (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/tracing-and-instrumenting-applications) and the TraceSource.TraceData and TraceSource.TraceEvent methods (and similar ones) look like they fit. However, how to implement this specifically for HttpWebRequest.GetResponse escapes me. Those methods are expecting trace data as arguments, while the network tracing docs imply it is automatic.

So either A) where's my magic log file or B) what do I do to output tracing for networking traffic?

```
<configuration> 
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
  <listeners>
    <add name="file" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\\MyApp\\bin\\Debug\\network.log"/>
  </listeners>
</trace>
<sources>
  <source name="System.Net" tracemode="protocolonly" maxdatasize="1024">
    <listeners>
      <add name="System.Net"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Net.Cache">
    <listeners>
      <add name="System.Net"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Net.Http">
    <listeners>
      <add name="System.Net"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
    <listeners>
      <add name="System.Net"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.Net.WebSockets">
    <listeners>
      <add name="System.Net"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<switches>
  <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
  <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Verbose"/>
  <add name="System.Net.Http" value="Verbose"/>
  <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
  <add name="System.Net.WebSockets" value="Verbose"/>
</switches>
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="System.Net"
       type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
       initializeData="C:\\MyApp\\bin\\Debug\\network.log"
       traceOutputOptions="ProcessId, DateTime"
  />
</sharedListeners>
<trace autoflush="true"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does your process have write access to the given location? You could also try just giving a file name, so that the file is created local to the executable. The original MSFT example does it this way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing